# how do I remove error message when signing into Power BI using onmicrosoft.com address

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created an email address by signing up to microsoft 365 free trial, so that I can use power bi at home. I am trying to sign into power bi using the onmicrosoft.com address, but I am getting the following error. Can anybody help me work out how to fix this? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Which version of Power BI Desktop are you running?